# I sent pepe from MetaMask to crypto.com

Tags: transactions, ether, metamask

I sent pepe coin from my MetaMask address to my crypto.com eth address it’s showing as completed but the it’s not showing this on my balance or can’t see it. Yet on ethascan it’s showing as a token? Am confused as I am
Quite new to this can anyone help. The transaction id is 0x9799a4e470177a698c1cb740252db87560dd07df8e5131be23d160fc2d9851d2

Answer (score 0):

The respective transaction only transfers 0.00897972894544 ETH from `0x114be15b5088ae7c667e6a407cdedb5f448a1f9c` to `0xd29983de21dbb93eb9eeed0e5909629bdab2d92a`, without transferring any ERC-20 tokens (like PEPE).

However, I see you've also transferred 15,518,673.19 PEPE to the same destination (`0xd29983de21dbb93eb9eeed0e5909629bdab2d92a`) in [another tx](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7e7e9c46ad6a02d65b5be986a004407606e52190f1c713303998322b279ecbdc) around 7m prior to the one you've referrenced in your question.

So, the PEPE tokens have been transferred to the respective destination. Unless the destination is wrong or crypto.com has some technical issues, the transfer should also reflect in your crypto.com account.

Now, are you sure `0xd29983de21dbb93eb9eeed0e5909629bdab2d92a` is the address you were supposed to transfer the PEPE to?